# Filter out overlapping data from array of data

Tags: python

I am having an array of data like this.

```
---------------------------------------
| Name | Start time | End time | Count|
---------------------------------------
|  A   | 5:00       | 5:30     | 10   |
|  B   | 5:00       | 5:45     | 20   |
|  C   | 5:36       | 5:50     | 30   |
|  D   | 5:43       | 5:55     | 40   |
|  E   | 5:56       | 6:00     | 50   |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to do :

```
1. Sum of Count of A and B since they are both overlapping. 
2. Sum of Count of B , C and D since they are both overlapping.
3. I want to store E in separate array since it is not overlapping with anyone.
```

Output in 2 arrays: -

```
Overlap Array
A, B => 30
B,C,D => 90

Non - Overlapping array
E => 50
```

Comment: `Sum of A and B` then ` Sum of B , C and D`??? what excatly do you want to be done? Add expected output.

Comment: How is ```A``` and ```B``` overlapping ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: updated. please check

Comment: Don't `B` and `C` overlap, too? `C` seems to start before `B` ends.

Comment: @cegas yes. your observation is correct

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that the second point mentions B, C, and D, not only C and D. My bad.

Comment: Hey @knotknot did my answer work for you? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it would be something like the following:

```py
for row in l:
  row['overlapping_count'] = 0
  for otherrow in l:
    if (row['start'] <= otherrow['start'] <= row['end']) or (row['start'] <= otherrow['end'] <= row['end']):
      row['overlapping_count'] += otherrow['count']
```

This will compute the overlapping count for each row. Be aware however that this is an O(n^2) algorithm, and it will not scale too well as you increment the amounts of data.